# How to draw Center gradient in Libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

How to draw Center gradient in Libgdx of android

the following effect

[image]

I haven't skilled in OpenGL of Libgdx...
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a texture or an OpenGL mesh?  Do you want to draw this on the screen?  Or in an off-screen buffer?  what have you tried and what works successfully for you?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way will be a PNG with transparency and loading the Texture from a Texture or TextureAtlas on the code. After that, adapt the position (setPosition) and scale (setScale) and you will have a similar efect on the screen.

You can create Circle, Rectangle,...but gradients. I don't think so. Check libGDX wiki.